# Textmate: .* regex not working

Tags: regex, textmate

I'm trying to find strings using this simple regex on TextMate but it's not matching anything: `<a.*href=".*">`

It's weird because I tried on sits like regexpal and it's indeed fine..

Answer (score 0):

In textMate 2, that regex is working just fine in the find dialog.

Make sure you've got the "Regular Expression" box checked